# The $Path from Sys.getenv() is different from what I get from CMD, and cannot be changed

Tags: r, path, operating-system, environment-variables

System is Windows 11, R version 4.2.0, RTools 4.2.

When I type check system variable in CMD, it shows:

```
C:\Users\username>echo %PATH%
C:\Strawberry\perl\bin
```

However when I run R from CMD, then run `Sys.getenv()` in R, the result is different:

```
> Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "C:\\rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/bin;C:\\rtools42/usr/bin;C:\\Strawberry\\perl\\bin"
```

Two items regarding `rtools42` appeared, and has higher priority above every other item in system $PATH. This causes `Sys.which("perl")` always points to the `rtools42` folder, not the one I set up in $PATH.

And I could not remove them: they only appear in `Sys.getenv()`, nowhere to be found in Control Panel or other Windows configs (that I could think of). So in administrator mode, I tried:

1. I tried uninstalling RTools and re-installing R, neither worked, the `rtools42` folders are still in `Sys.getenv("PATH")`.
2. I used `Sys.setenv(PATH="everything-except-the-rtools42-folders")` in R terminal to override the $PATH. It worked in the specific R session; but after I restart R, these two paths returned.
3. I set my `.Renviron` like this:

```
PATH="${PATH};${RTOOLS42_HOME}\usr\bin"
```

Still nothing changed.

So how did those `rtools42` paths sneak into $PATH? How can I remove them?

Comment: Are you using RStudio? Or the default R terminal/GUI. Do you have an `.Rprofile` file in your home directory?

Comment: @MrFlick I used default R GUI, also tried running R from command prompt. I just figured the problem, it is indeed a line from `Rprofile` (not exactly `.Rprofile`, not sure if it is the same thing, I'm noob). I'll update an answer

Answer (score 2):

I solved my own question. The problem is in the file `Rprofile`. On my computer, its location is `Program Files\R\R-4.2.0\library\base\R\`. At the end of the file there are these lines:

```
local({
    setRtools42Path <- 0
     setRtools42Path <- 1

    if (setRtools42Path) {
        rthome <- Sys.getenv("RTOOLS42_HOME", "c:/rtools42")
        rtpath <- paste0(rthome, "/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/bin;",
                         rthome, "/usr/bin")
        path <- Sys.getenv("R_CUSTOM_TOOLS_PATH", rtpath)
        Sys.setenv(R_RTOOLS42_PATH = rtpath)
        Sys.setenv(PATH = paste0(path, ";", Sys.getenv("PATH")))
    }
})
```

I changed the line

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste0(path, ";", Sys.getenv("PATH")))
```

to

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste0(Sys.getenv("PATH"), ";", path))
```

And the $PATH arranges as I intended now:

```
C:\Users\username>echo %PATH%
C:\Strawberry\perl\bin

C:\Users\username>r

R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt) -- "Vigorous Calisthenics"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "C:\\Strawberry\\perl\\bin;C:\\rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/bin;C:\\rtools42/usr/bin"
```

---

P.S. There's also another file `Program Files\R\R-4.2.0\etc\Rcmd_environ` which ends with following lines:

```
R_RTOOLS42_PATH="${RTOOLS42_HOME:-c:/rtools42}/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/bin;${RTOOLS42_HOME:-c:/rtools42}/usr/bin"
#   trailing slash to protect against trailing backslash in PATH
PATH="${R_CUSTOM_TOOLS_PATH:-${R_RTOOLS42_PATH}};${PATH}/"
```

I also changed to

```
R_RTOOLS42_PATH="${RTOOLS42_HOME:-c:/rtools42}/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/bin;${RTOOLS42_HOME:-c:/rtools42}/usr/bin"
PATH="${PATH}/;${R_CUSTOM_TOOLS_PATH:-${R_RTOOLS42_PATH}}"
```

But only doing this alone won't change the order in `Sys.getenv("PATH")`. Not sure if I should or shouldn't do this.